# Синоним к выражению "с подачи"

Tags: грамотная-речь, синонимы

Российские  мусульмане с подачи президента В. Путина обозначили как свою стратегическую задачу на ближайшие годы - воссоздание отечественной мусульманской богословской школы. Можно ли в данном контексте написать "с подачи" (не слишком ли "вульгарно" с президентом?) или лучше "по предложению"?

Comment: А что фактически произошло? Путин предложил воссоздать отечественную мусульманскую богословскую школу?

Comment: Чтобы написать "по предложению", нужно точно знать, что такое предложение было.

Comment: Он сказал, что это необходимо (не цитата - общий смысл).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> «Подчеркну: государство будет и впредь помогать воссозданию отечественной мусульманской богословской школы, своей системы религиозного образования. Как вы знаете, мною поддержано предложение руководства Татарстана и ведущих духовных управлений мусульман о создании Булгарской исламской академии», - сказал Путин

Получается, что Путин поддержал, а не посоветовал. Поэтому я бы поостерегся писать как "с подачи", так и "по совету". Может быть, "при поддержке"?

**При поддержке президента Путина российские мусульмане обозначили воссоздание отечественной мусульманской богословской школы как свою стратегическую задачу на ближайшие годы.**

Примечание. "Обозначили как свою стратегическую задачу — воссоздание..." исправлено на  "обозначили воссоздание... как свою стратегическую задачу".

Или так:

**При поддержке президента Путина российские мусульмане объявили** (если было такое объявлено) **воссоздание отечественной мусульманской богословской школы своей стратегической задачей на ближайшие годы.**

Примечание. На мой взгляд, лучше писать "президент Путин", чем "президент В. Путин".

> «Сделать всё для России»: речь **президента Путина** на церемонии вступления в должность (https://russian.rt.com/russia/article/510301-rech-prezidenta-putina-inauguraciya)

Answer (score 3):

Слишком. Да и вообще фраза корявая. Например, "обозначили *как* свою стратегическую задачу".

Answer (score 2):

В данном контексте нельзя. И не потому, что "вульгарно с президентом" (в словарях это выражение не помечено как просторечное или сниженное), а из-за смешения стилей. "С подачи" соответствует разговорному стилю, а каждое слово контекста — "стратегическая задача", "ближайшие годы", "воссоздание отечественной мусульманской богословской школы" и т.д. — официально-деловому.